# Deleting a project from TFS

Tags: tfs

I would like to delete the project named 'Test' from TFS.

[image]

I already try:

```
(dos prompt)
TFSDeleteProject /force /collection:https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection Test
```

It doesn't work because Test project is located under yyyyyyyy

Any idea how to proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test` doesn't seem to be a TFS project. It is a folder inside the `yyyyyyyy` TFS project. In order to delete it you simply use the <kbd>Del</kbd> (<kbd>Suppr.</kbd> in your case) on your keyboard while hovering over the `Test` folder in the source explorer. You could also right click on the `Test` folder and choose to delete it from the context menu. Then simply check-in the pending changes on the `yyyyyyyy` project.

Comment: I have no way to delete this 'folder'. In the contextual menu, the 'Delete' option is grayed out. I also try to press the del key on my keyboard. Note that I'm the only one person using this TFS environment. Do I miss some privileges? How to get that permission? Thanks anyway.

Comment: In order to delete a folder there shouldn't be any pending changes. Make sure you check everything in before attempting to delete it. As far as permissions are concerned you will have to contact your TFS server administrator and ask him if you have the necessary permissions.

Comment: I don't have anything checked out. I also unmap the folder. I don't have any TFS server administrator (I work for myself). I check permissions and I'm member of Project Administrators + Project Collection Administrators + Team Foundation Administrators. Any idea?

Comment: Problem solved. I had to map (again). Suddently I had the possibility to delete the folder. Thank you.